# Replacing text inside a textarea box

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<textarea name="comment"><p>Good job.</p></textarea>
```

Using JavaScript, I'd like to replace "Good job" with "Here's how I graded your assignment:".

I'm not comfortable with string replacement yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure Javascript solution:

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementsByName("comment")[0];
myTextArea.value = myTextArea.value.replace("Good job", "Here's how I graded your assignment:");
```

It'd be better to give your `textarea` and id and select it using `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have jquery on your user profile. so here is an answer using it:

```
$('textarea[name="comment"]').text("<p>Here's how I graded your assignment:</p>");
```

i would recommend adding a class to the textarea and selecting it via the class. The code above assumes you dont have another textarea with the name 'comment' on the page.

this would be better:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="some-better-name-here"><p>Good job.</p></textarea>
$('textarea.some-better-name-here').text("<p>Here's how I graded your assignment:</p>");
```

here it is in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/MCVbg/