# Using Javascript to replace unique characters in a textarea box

Tags: javascript, textarea

I want to use Javascript to catch a character when it's typed into a textarea box and swap it out with another one. However unlike [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199287/replacing-text-inside-a-textarea-box), I want a unique character for every letter.

So `.replace("This guy", "With this guy");` as soon as it's typed into the textarea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And you tried ... what?

Comment: Do you want to replace one character with another or a longer phrase like in your example. This makes quite some difference. If it's just one character, you can use a `keydown` eventlistener to replace that character. [MDN Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) and [MDN Keyboard Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) should help you out for the start.

Comment: Replace a character with another character. Apologies, poor choice of example text. 

.replace("1", "2");

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('txtarea').onkeydown = function(){
    var txt = this.innerHTML;
    if(txt.indexOf('This guy') != -1)
        txt.replace('This guy', 'With this guy');
}
```

Comment: -1 for a squishy non-standardized method. The only way to go is [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). Omitting `{}` is also a bad habit, especially when teaching beginners. Furthermore use regex and not strings in the replace method.

Comment: @Christoph addEventListener is not browser compatible method (attachEvent for IE). Then i should have written method called addEvent which would consider this. But I don't think that this question requires such detailed event binding explanation. Downvoter

Comment: Actually I have one as a programmer who writes clean, standardconform and solid code:-p

Comment: @Christoph Frankly I see nothing that ugly in karaxuna's example. As of the other two of your arguments, omitting {} is not as horrible as you describe and regular expressions would be somewhat overwhelming for a beginner. +1 from me :)

Comment: @Christoph And you are spending your valuable time arguing with me :D

Comment: Thanks karaxuna. 

@Christoph What would be your solution to this?